# How to configure application directories within the Visual Studio web sever?

Tags: .net, session, iis, web-config

I need to use a different Session Mode for a directory within my application. The reason for this is because we use Crystal Reports and the Visual Studio version of Crystal does not support Serialization. Therefore I intend to use **InProc** Session mode for my Crystal Viewer and **StateServer** for the rest of my application.

However when I try to configure this I get this error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as 
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
```

I understand to allow this I have to convert my Report/ directory to an Application in IIS, but how can I do this within the built in VS Web Server?

I'd prefer not to have to move to IIS on my local development environment if I could avoid it.

Comment: Hmm...do you intend to "share sessions"? Then I don't know if actually possible to have 2 **different** sessions stores in 1 application. If you end up *sharing*, then wouldn't that mean you have 2 applications?